# How do you list your commits along with their SHA1 values in git?

Tags: git

How do you list your commits along with their SHA1 values in git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly what format do you want?  For just the one line summary and the SHA1:

```
git log --pretty=oneline
```

See git log --help for more formating options.

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I have an alias for that: `git config --global alias.lg "log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --decorate"` Using `--decorate` also lists tags and branches in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean.  Listing a commit *is* listing its hash, and the easiest way to do it is with git rev-list.

```
$ git rev-list HEAD
```

will give the the reverse chronological list of all commits reachable from the current HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

While P00ya's answer is correct, newer versions of git allow a simpler syntax:

```
git log --oneline
```

which is shorthand for `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` used together.